# Error accessing table through Link server

Tags: sql-server

While trying to access a table using a link server, I am getting the below error:

```
SELECT * FROM
[LinkServerName].[DestinationDBName].[SchemaName].[ViewName]


-------------------------------------
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LinkServeName" does not contain the table ""DBName"."CI"."ViewName"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.
-----------------------------------------
```

At the same time, if I try to select this table from the destination server directly this works fine. I'm not sure where the problem could be. If there would have been a problem accessing it, then I would not have been able to access from the server directly.

The link server is fine as it is able to fetch data from other database.

Comment: If you're positive that the object exists on the destination server, then you cdon't have permission to `SELECT` data from it. Linked Servers don't always use the same credentials of the Login you're connected as; as I would guess it's using a different login, and that login doesn't have the needed permissions. I check to see what login is used to connect to the linked server and adjust the login appropriately, or change the permissions at the linked server,.

Comment: Likely the linked server account does not have the same permissions as you do in SSMS.

Comment: The user you use to access the linked server is not necessarily the same as you're using for selecting the data directly, as you can configure security mappings. Try `EXEC ('SELECT @@SERVERNAME, USER_NAME(), SUSER_NAME()') AT [LinkedServerName]`. (The `@@SERVERNAME` is useful to confirm that you end up at the server you're expecting to end up; this could have been changed through DNS or `sp_setnetname`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for Quick response. Yes , i think this is right. i have got access to the Destination server as part of a group ID but trying to access using my Individual Id. so that means even though my ID is part of that group i will not be able to access that over the Link server.